# `rails new` not using ruby version from rbenv and from `ruby -v` while rails s throws 'Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, gemfile

I am using rbenv for ruby version management and I just generated a new project with `rails new ...` I realized that my gemfile und .ruby-version were using 2.6.3 so I changed to 2.7.2, since it is my global ruby version in rbenv. But now when I run rails s I get `Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2` even though `ruby -v`, `rbenv local` and `rbenv global` are showing 2.7.2

```rb
❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-darwin20]
❯ rbenv local
2.7.2
❯ rbenv global
2.7.2
❯ rails s
Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2
```

I tried to reinstall ruby 2.7.2 and use `rbenv rehash`, resetting global and local without anything changing actually. I also tried `bundle install` and `bundle update` with `rbenv rehash` aftwards. Nothing changing.

Any idea what is going on here and why `rails new` is not taking my global rbenv ruby version?

Comment: did you try to `gem install bundler` and `rbenv rehash` ? there is a chance that you are using bundler installed for ruby 2.6.3?

Comment: I tried this and when generating a new rails project it still runs on 2.6.3

Comment: What is the output of `which rails`? Perhaps that command is running some unexpected binstub, or you've got a dodgy `$PATH` variable. Also, does re-entering the folder (`cd .`) fix the issue?

Comment: which rails gives me /usr/local/bin/rails. In my path there was something messed up. Thanks a lot, I feel quite released now, since this helped me with some other bugs as well.

Comment: This may be stupid but it has happened to me before... where are you executing `rbenv local` from?

Comment: how can I find out? where should which rails actually be pointing to? It actually changed directory back to /usr/local/bin/rails though it was meanwhile to .rbenv/...